# Controller action called with old parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

here in my company we can't instantiate a controller for each new request. We have to store it in the session and re-utilize it every time, i know this is wrong, but we have to keep the state of the controller between requests. So here's what we did:

We created this controller factory:

```
public class SGVControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
    {

        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            string _SessionId = controllerName + "Controller";
            foreach (var _Object in HttpContext.Current.Session)
            {
                if (_Object.ToString() == _SessionId)
                {
                    IController _Controller = (IController)HttpContext.Current.Session[_Object.ToString()];



                    return _Controller;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        public SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            return SessionStateBehavior.Default;
        }


        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            //We never release our controllers!!!
        }
    }
```

And we have this base controller:

```
public class SGVController : Controller
    {
        protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
            }
            if (requestContext.HttpContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Http context is null", "requestContext");
            }

            Initialize(requestContext);

            using (ScopeStorage.CreateTransientScope())
            {                
                ExecuteCore();
                Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

The only thing this controller class does differently from the default MVC controller is that it doesn't limit itself to be called just once.

Now, my problem is..  if I have this action:

```
public JsonResult Foo(string Bar) {
 return Json(new List<string> { Bar, Bar });
}
```

The 'Bar' parameter will aways have the value of the first call to the action. I can't find anything that explains that. The request parameter dictionary has the right values, but the action still gets the old value.

Comment: This is like bad, very bad pattern... Why didn't you extract what you need to persist in some static class? Static classes are shared between different HttpContext instances.

Comment: I know it's VERY bad, but what we had is worse. My boss is not very fond of changes in the way we work so i'm trying to change things very slowly. 
And I think your aproach could make things messier(I have a lot of data that i neet to persist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to reinit the ValueProvider and the TempData by overriding the Initialize method to have the new values being handled.

```
public class SGVController : Controller
{

  protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
   {
    this.TempData = null;
    this.ValueProvider = null;

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
   }        

    protected override void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
        }
        if (requestContext.HttpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Http context is null", "requestContext");
        }

        Initialize(requestContext);

        using (ScopeStorage.CreateTransientScope())
        {                
            ExecuteCore();
            Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help,

Comment: Yeah, this worked, thanks man. (But controller.TempDataDictionary doesn't exist, it's just TempData here)