# How to make the Controller a single instance per application in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Over time controllers develop a lot of dependencies, and creating an instance of controller becomes too expensive for each request (especially with DI). Is there any solution to make controllers singletons?

Comment: You can [make your own controller factory](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=878) easily... but are you asking about the possible downsides of *using* single instance controllers?

Comment: In fact, i've already made my controllers 'single instance per application', but it doesn't work: '..If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.'

Comment: While nothing is impossible, I suggest that trying to implement this would cause more problems than answers. For instance the HttpContext property of an instance of a controller is obviously unique to that request. First of probably many problems you could encounter.

Comment: Answered a question a while ago, to help someone reuse a Controller, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15522909/1236044 The question features some factory implementation, and I guess the question's owner might be able to help you.

Comment: The comment from @Mark is spot on. As an alternative, could you encapsulate your business logic into singleton classes that are isolated from things like the HttpContext and then call these classes from the controllers? The controller instantiation could then be kept quite lightweight.

Comment: Thanks for Your comments, guys! I understand, that with current implementation of base Controller it is impossible to make controller single instance:( But i hope that there could be some hack to make request pipeline not so tied to controller instance

Comment: wow, you're so brave to put a bounty of 500, leaving you with 66 reputation only. commendable!

Comment: I don't have an idea how to spent it different way))

Comment: As a hint to the bounty hunter: an implementation of IController with all the logic from ControllerBase, but without tying to controller instance could be the best answer:)

Comment: Thinking about this slightly differently, could you not just make more of your dependencies singletons, which in turn would reduce controller initialiser time not just for a single controller but throughout the application?

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of answering people's questions with "you don't want to do that" (because in many cases, people have a good reason). However, in this case, I have to agree with most of the others here. If controller instantiation becomes a bottle neck, it's because your controller isn't a controller anymore - it's a sign that it's handed *way* too much responsibility. And, as Mark pointed out, there's a good reason why it's not a singleton - the one dependency of `IController` is `RequestContext`. Which is a hint of what a controller is - *all* it is: A handler of a (single) request.

Comment: RequestContext is a dependency of ContollerBase, not a IContoller... By the way, ASP.NET MVC is just a makeover of Monorail there Contollers are free to be used as singletons. Another example is WCF, there Services could be singletons also. So i think of it as just implementation fault(from MS).

Comment: RequestContext could be accessed from singleton Controller via System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items so i see no point to stick with Contoller per request

Answer (score 32):

Creating instances of controllers is pretty fast and simple operation. What becomes too expensive is creating dependencies for each request. So, what you really need is many controllers which share same instances of dependencies.

E.g. you have following controller

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository productRepository;
    private IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    public SalesController(IProductRepository productRepository,
                           IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    // ...       
}
```

You should configure your dependency injection framework to use same instances of repositories for all application (keep in mind, you can have synchronization problems). Now creating dependencies is not expensive any more. All dependencies are instantiated only once, and reused for all requests.

If you have many dependencies and you are worrying about costs of getting reference to instance of each dependency and providing these references to controller instance (which I don't think will be very expensive), then you can group your dependencies (something like Introduce Parameter Object refactoring):

```
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    private ISalesService salesService;

    public SalesController(ISalesService salesService)
    {
        this.salesService = salesService;
    }

    // ...       
}

public class SalesService : ISalesService
{
    private IProductRepository productRepository;
    private IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    public SalesService(IProductRepository productRepository,
                           IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    // ...       
}
```

Now you have single dependency, which will be injected very quickly. If you will configure your dependency injection framework to use singleton SalesService, then all SalesControllers will reuse same instance of service. Creation of controllers and providing dependencies will be very fast.

Comment: Very good and detailed aswer, thanks! It is my last resort if there is no solution[hack] to make controllers singletons... Too much refactoring and xml-magic(i'm using spring)

Comment: surely the synchronization problems will be too high a price to pay

Answer (score 11):

So first an answer to the original question:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // put other services bindings here

    // bind all Controller classes as singletons
    services.AddSingleton<HomeController, HomeController>();

    // tell framework to obtain Controller instances from ServiceProvider.
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
}
```

As stated in the original question, if controllers have big dependency trees consisting mainly of request Scoped or Transient dependencies then creating them separately for each request may have some footprint on scalability of your application (in Java for example Servlet instances are singletons by default exactly for this reason). While usually CPU and real time needed to create even a big dependency tree is negligible (unless you have some heavy computations or network communication in constructors of your components, which almost never is a good idea for transient or request scoped components), the memory usage footprint is something to reckon with. In case of common DB-Web apps memory is the main factor limiting number of concurrent requests that a single machine-node can handle. If every request has a separate copy of a big dependency tree, together they may consume a significant amount of memory (the other thing to watch for is initial stack size for a new thread, by the way).

The accepted answer 1220560 solves the problem as well, but I would consider it an ugly hack and it has some drawbacks: you need to create this artificial singleton service that will be used by your Controllers either as a service locator or a proxy for other services. If you have just one such singleton object for all your controllers then you are effectively hiding real dependencies of your Controller: for example if someone wants to write a unit-test for your Controller he needs to analyse carefully its implementation to see which dependencies it actually uses, so that he knows what mocks/fakes he needs to provide in his test setup. If later you change your Controller and as a result of your change the subset of services your controller uses changes as well, it is very easy to forget to update the test setup also. This may sometimes lead to bugs that are hard to track. Contrary to this, if your dependencies are declared explicitly as constructor params, you will get a compiler error in the test setup right away. Another thing you can do is to have a separate such a singleton proxy/service locator for each controller, but then it's a lot of hassle basically.

Regardless whether you use the solution proposed by me or the one from answer #1220560 you must be careful when injecting request Scoped dependencies into singleton objects as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#registering-your-own-services right at the end of the "registering-your-own-services" section. You can find possible solutions to this problem here: [how to use scoped dependency in a singleton in C# / ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544187/how-to-use-scoped-dependency-in-a-singleton-in-c-sharp-asp/40563455)
Another thing to watch for is concurrency issue: singleton objects may be accessed concurrently by several threads handling different concurrent requests, so make sure to add proper synchronization to any non-thread-safe resources your singleton uses.

**edit:**

I've just realized the original question was about ASP.NET and this answer is for ASP.NET Core, so it probably won't work for "non-Core".