# how to use scoped dependency in a singleton in C# / ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I'm new to C#/ASP coming from a Java world. I've read this article: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options which wisely warns about the dangers associated with injecting a dependency with a smaller scope. Unfortunately it does not explain how to solve this issue in C#/ASP.
In Java there's a concept of Provider

```
interface Provider<T> { T get(); }
```

which, among other things helps to solve the scoping issue:
whenever a binding for some type T is register we can inject an automatically generated instance of Provider<T> instead of T and then get an instance of T whenever it is needed: an automatically generated Provider makes sure that we get an instance appropriate for the current scope (whatever this scope is: HTTP request, HTTP session or other custom scopes). The standard DI framework built into ASP.NET core does not have anything like this, but I thought in C# it should be very easy to implement as C# generics don't suck like java's do (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). So I've created the following class:

```
public class Provider<T>: IProvider<T> {
  private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
  public Provider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  }
  public T IProvider<T>.Get() {
    return serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
  }
}
```

and I attemtped to use it the following way:

```
public class SingletonService : ISingletonService {
  private readonly IProvider<IScopedService> scopedServiceProvider;

  public SingletonService(IProvider<IScopedService> scopedServiceProvider) {
    this.scopedServiceProvider = scopedServiceProvider;
  }

  public string PerformMyTask() {
    var scopedDependency = scopedServiceProvider.Get();
    // do something with scopedDependency to verify we get instances
    // appropriate for the current scope
  }
}
```

and in my Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
  services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();
  services.AddTransient<IProvider<IScopedService>, Provider<IScopedService>>();
  // other bindings here
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work the way I intended as IServiceProvider instance seems to be also scoped to the current HTTP request and I get exactly the same instance of ScopedDependency from my provider during processing of different requests :(

Any hints how can I solve this problem?
Is there any "higher level" object than ServiceProvider maybe, bound roughly to application lifecycle (not to the current request) that creates instances of request scoped objects (or of ServiceProvider itself) that I can inject into my Provider objects instead of ServiceProvider? For example in Java if I use google Guice as a DI framework there is an Injector object, usually created at the startup of an application which holds all the type bindings and has a method

```
<T> T getInstance(Class<T> type);
```

which checks what is the current scope and returns a corresponding instance.

**edit:**

I think that one possible way to do it would be to get a new reference to instance of ServiceProvider each time in the Proivder<T>.Get() method instead of injecting in the constructor and storing as an instance var. This way my components would still not be polluted with a reference to the framework specific IServiceProvider as it would be hidden from them in the implementation of Provider<T> that they access via the abstract IProvider<T> interface.  I can't however find on the web if it's possible to get such a reference from my Provider class and how to do this. Any pointers in this direction would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Do I miss it or you never show how and when the ServiceProvider is instantiated? Also, it is unclear why you try to reinvent a di framework while having so many of them available.

Comment: Is Provider even needed? Couldn't you just use the built in ServiceProvider?

Comment: @Wiktor: ServiceProvider is a framework managed class: it is instantiated and Injected to Provider<T>  by framework. I don't exactly understand what do you mean by "reinvent a DI framework": what I'm trying to do is to find/create a mechanism to use dependencies of smaller scope (for example of SCOPED in a SINGLETON component) in a nice and safe way. If you know such way then please just point me into this instead of just stating "so many of them available" which is not really helpful.

Comment: @Matt, it is possible to inject ServiceProvider to all your components instead of specific dependencies, but it's not a good practice: you bind your components to a specific implementation of DI framework and you obscure  a list of actual dependencies (if someone writes a unit test for your component, he must go through all usages of ServiceProvider inside your code to check what dependencies are actually obtained to provide mock bindings for them in the setup of his unit test). Finally it doesn't really help to use scoped dependencies in singletons as ServiceProvider is also request scoped.

Comment: I would assume dependencies are mocked when writing unit tests for a component. DI should never come into the equation when unit testing, unless you're testing that functionality explicitly.

Comment: @Matt: exactly, you answered your own question ;) that's why it's not a good idea to inject a part of DI framework such as ServiceProvider into your classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, found it:

```
public class Provider<T> : IProvider<T> {
    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
    public Provider(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
    T IProvider<T>.Get() {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<T>();
    }
}
```

and in Startup:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISingletonService, SingletonService>();
        services.AddScoped<IScopedService, ScopedService>();
        services.AddTransient<IProvider<IScopedService>, Provider<IScopedService>>();
        // other bindings
    }
```

:)

see https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793 for more details about using and registering HttpContextAccessor

Comment: If you are using advanced scenarios for DI, I would advise not to use default implementation, but to plug-in some DI-container, like e.g. brilliant  `SimpleInjector`. There are other popular ones that you can google and chose from. They usually have a number of advanced scenarios including the Factory (seems to me the Provider is a Factory, but not sure).

Comment: thanks for the pointer to other framework, @IlyaChernomordik! I'll check it out. Provider is not exactly a factory: it may be a wrapper around factory though. Generally, it's an object containing logic whom to delegate a call to get a new instance of service to (for example in the case described by me in this answer it makes sure that the call is delegated to an instance of ServiceProvider appropriate for the current request)

Comment: Thanks so much, this clarified a lot for me coming from a Guice world and trying to make a `Provider` like utility.
Seems like `services.AddSingleton<IProvider<IScopedService>, ...` works for me. Do you think that's ok?

Comment: BTW you can do `services.AddTransient(typeof(IProvider<>), typeof(Provider<>));` to make it more general.

Comment: There is now `IAsyncContext` which works very similarly for holding object, but doesn't use the `RequestServices` so it does not create the objects for you: https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/tree/main/src/Libraries/Microsoft.AspNetCore.AsyncState