# ASP.NET Core Dependecy Injection scoped dependecies for singleton objects

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inject

In ASP.NET Core Dependecy Injection implementation dependencies of an object are resolved at object creation time and objects get direct reference to the dependency. This seems to be the case with Autofac too. So if we have a Repository and DbContext we must make both of them scoped, because singleton repository wont work.

In comparison DI frameworks in java world (CDI, Spring IoC) inject proxies instead of actual dependencies which enable to resolve the dependecy object everytime you use that dependency. So we can have singleton repositories, because injected request scope entityManager will be different on every request.

I wanted to ask why .net's frameworks don't do it like java frameworks? Also, what are pros and cons of both approaches?

By the way, a question which tries to solve it in .net - 
[how to use scoped dependency in a singleton in C# / ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544187/how-to-use-scoped-dependency-in-a-singleton-in-c-sharp-asp)

Comment: Java DI frameworks are more advanced at least compared to ASP.NET core, there are no cons. Other .NET frameworks might offer the same features.

Comment: I understand that .Net Core default implementation is not advanced. But other .NET DI frameworks have similiar functionality in this aspect. Why is that?

Comment: The question you linked to mentions `SimpleInjector` as a DI framework with more advanced features.